# Woocommerce filter function not updating

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, exclude

I have a simple function to exclude a few categories from my Woocommerce shop page.
This is the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args' );
function woo_product_cat_widget_args( $cat_args ) {
$cat_args['exclude'] = '12, 13';
return $cat_args;
}
```

Which works like a charm. However, I have now added another category that I'd like to exclude with ID 22. So I tried adding that ID as well like: '12, 13, 22'; but when I save nothing happens, the category is still there.

So just as a test, I removed ID 13 and 22 but Category 13 doesn't appear either. I tried clearing my web browsers cache and also another browser but still the same result.

I am not using a cache plugin like W3 Total Cashe etc at this stage.

Any idea on how I can resolve this? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar code that is working fine for me. Try putting your ids into an array like so:

```
$cat_args['exclude'] = array('12, 13');
```